# IS Spring Context and Spring IOC container both are same and ApplicationContext is part of it?

Tags: spring

I know what is application Context. It is an interface which provides spring beans.

All beans get initialized in Spring IOC containers.

But How all three are connected. Could you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring beans are the instances of classes that spring manages. You create classes and "mark" them to be spring managed (putting `@Component`, using `@Bean` in java configuration and so forth - there are many ways to tell spring that the instance of some particular class should be managed by spring)

When spring starts it creates an application context with is a registry of all beans it resolves.

Spring can inject one bean into another and its the way of spring to instantiate beans. 
The principle of "providing dependencies by external container" as opposed to  maintaining dependencies by class itself called Inversion of control, and spring implements this concept.

**Update 1**

There is no such a thing as "spring context" technically speaking

Spring IOC container is a framework that manages the beans (your classes) by means of providing a technical abstraction called application context (its a real interface in java with implementation inside the spring code).

In order to benefit from spring your Beans should have dependencies between them. In this case spring framework that implements IOC principle can "inject" (provide, resolve) dependencies between beans.

Here is an example:

```
@Component
class A {

}

@Component
class B {
  @Autowired
  private A a;
}
```

When spring container instantiates class B (creates the object : `new B()`) it "understands" that this instance (we call it bean because it's managed by spring) has a "dependency" on class A and since A is also managed by spring, it can "inject" (read put a value) into the property a of class B.

This is called an Inversion of Control. You, as a programmer do not have to instantiate property `b` by yourself, spring does it for you.

Comment: Mark  Thanks for your explanation. I got applicationContext. Could you please explain Spring Context and Spring IOC Container in this scenario. It would help.

Comment: Please see the update 1, Hope it makes things more clear